# [FLUTTER]: How many notifications can I set in my Flutter App for iOS and Android each?

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, android-notifications, localnotification

Currently I'am working on Flutter App which should act like alarm for different todo lists. I need to set every todo list tile for pushing me notifications every, let's say, 5 hours during a week. And I will probably have a lot of todos, which will have own notification. So I have two questions? Is this possible to apply every notification locally as a group notifications without using FCM.
The second one is about the local notifications limit. I read from this page [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) that iOS has about 60 notificatios limitation for every App. And I can't understand if it's true or not? Maybe I've got it wrong? And what about Android Apps. Have they any notification limits per app?